# Flutter - странное поведение ReorderableList при itemExtent != null

Tags: flutter

Задал `ReorderableList` `itemExtent` и появился странный отступ при сортировке. Как можно его пофиксить?

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0c44aabd37c20507c109b0a9bb6ed34b&null_safety=true)

[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => ReorderableListView(
    itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[
      for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          key: Key('$index'),
          color: Colors.blue[200 + index % 5 * 100],
          child: Center(child: Text('${_items[index]}')),
        ),
    ],
    onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
      setState(() {
        if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
          newIndex -= 1;
        }
        final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
        _items.insert(newIndex, item);
      });
    },
  );
```

Comment: Issue [#84901](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84901) без движения